# Show content of a picturebox after mouseclick

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I am trying to display a image in pictureBox after I click on it.

First I tried to set PictureBox property for visibility to false and after I click on PictureBox these option come true and the picture should be displayed. 
It does not work. 
Please tell me what the best practice for this operation is.

This is my List of PictureBoxes

```
List<PictureBox> logos = new List<PictureBox>();
//Here how I put Images into every single PictureBox:

 private void f1()
    {
        Insert_Logo();
        PictureBox picture;
        int randomnumber;

        for(int i=0; i< tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            if (tableLayoutPanel1.Controls[i] is PictureBox)
            {                      
                    picture = (PictureBox)tableLayoutPanel1.Controls[i];
            }
            else
                continue;

            randomnumber = random.Next(0, logos.Count);
            picture.Image = logos[randomnumber].Image;             
            logos.RemoveAt(randomnumber);                
        }

    }
```

And this is the function where I tried to display the image after I click on PictureBox:

```
    private void PictuteBox_CLICK(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        PictureBox clickedPicture = sender as PictureBox;

        if(clickedPicture == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (firsPic == null)
        {
            firsPic = clickedPicture;
            firsPic.Visible = true;
            return;
        }

    }
```

And this is the code for the Insert the pictures in PictureBox:

```
       private List<PictureBox> Insert_Logo()
    {
        PictureBox pic1 = new PictureBox();
        Image image = Image.FromFile("D:\\Project\\Mini-Game\\Mini-Game\\bin\\Image\\Renault.bmp");
        pic1.Image = image;

        PictureBox pic2 = new PictureBox();
        Image a = Image.FromFile("D:\\Project\\Mini-Game\\Mini-Game\\bin\\Image\\vw.bmp");
        pic2.Size = new Size(a.Width, a.Height);
        pic2.Image = a;

        PictureBox pic3 = new PictureBox();
        Image s = Image.FromFile("D:\\Project\\Mini-Game\\Mini-Game\\bin\\Image\\alfa.bmp");
        pic3.Size = new Size(s.Width, s.Height);
        pic3.Image = s;

        logos.Add(pic1);
        logos.Add(pic2);
        logos.Add(pic3);
        logos.Add(pic4);
        logos.Add(pic5);
        logos.Add(pic6);

return logos;
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough and what error do you get?

Comment: Hello @preciousbetine! After click the PictureBox nothing happens

Comment: Is the picturebox visible before you click it?

Comment: Yes it is visible. And the content in it also is visible.

Comment: Where is the code for your `Insert_Logo()` function ?

Comment: I will add it. One moment please.

Comment: I guess what you are trying to do is when you click the picturebox, a random image from the list is shown in the picturebox

Comment: Yess this is the idea of the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should write your code like this, explanations are commented

```
List<PictureBox> logos = new List<PictureBox>();   
private List<PictureBox> Insert_Logo()
{
    PictureBox pic1 = new PictureBox();
    Image image = Image.FromFile("D:\\Project\\Mini-Game\\Mini-Game\\bin\\Image\\Renault.bmp");
    pic1.Image = image;

    PictureBox pic2 = new PictureBox();
    Image a = Image.FromFile("D:\\Project\\Mini-Game\\Mini-Game\\bin\\Image\\vw.bmp");
    pic2.Size = new Size(a.Width, a.Height);
    pic2.Image = a;

    PictureBox pic3 = new PictureBox();
    Image s = Image.FromFile("D:\\Project\\Mini-Game\\Mini-Game\\bin\\Image\\alfa.bmp");
    pic3.Size = new Size(s.Width, s.Height);
    pic3.Image = s;

    logos.Add(pic1);
    logos.Add(pic2);
    logos.Add(pic3);
    return logos;
}

private void PictuteBox_CLICK(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    logos = Insert_Logo();
    //The Insert_Logo function returns a list of pictureboxes.
    int randomnumber;
    randomnumber = random.Next(0, logos.Count);
    //Replace Picturebox with the name of the picturebox you want to show the image in
    Picturebox.Image = logos[randomnumber].Image;
    logos.RemoveAt(randomnumber); 
}
```